# /usr/lib/libpthread.so: No such file or directory && /usr/lib/libm.so: No such file or directory Solutioned

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, centos

Solutioned with `sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libm.so /lib` and `ln -s /usr/lib64/libpthread.so /lib`

libm.so is in this directory: /usr/lib64/libm.so
libpthread is in this dir : /usr/lib64/libpthread.so

I tried `ln -s /usr/lib/libthread.so /lib64/libpthread.so` and the same error appears, Does the machine needs a reboot?

I am having problems making the client OPENDMTP in C with Centos 6.3

my source files: https://sourceforge.net/projects/opendmtp/files/client-c/1.2.3/

I installed :  `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`

I tried to install the needed libraries but they are already installed.

Trying : `"make dest=linux dmtp"`  I get the next :

```
[root@localhost OpenDMTP_client-c_1.2.0]# make dest=linux dmtp

Make tools dirs ...
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/tools
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/lib


Make './build_lin/obj/lib/libtools.a' ...
ar rc ./build_lin/obj/lib/libtools.a ./build_lin/obj/tools/checksum.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/base64.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/bintools.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/buffer.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/gpstools.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/strtools.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/utctools.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/threads.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/sockets.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/io.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/comport.o ./build_lin/obj/tools/random.o
ranlib ./build_lin/obj/lib/libtools.a

Make module dirs ...
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/modules
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/lib


Make './build_lin/obj/lib/libmodule.a' ...
ar rc ./build_lin/obj/lib/libmodule.a ./build_lin/obj/modules/odometer.o ./build_lin/obj/modules/motion.o ./build_lin/obj/modules/geozone.o
ranlib ./build_lin/obj/lib/libmodule.a

Make base dirs ...
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/base
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/lib


Make './build_lin/obj/lib/libbase.a' ...
ar rc ./build_lin/obj/lib/libbase.a ./build_lin/obj/base/mainloop.o ./build_lin/obj/base/propman.o ./build_lin/obj/base/event.o ./build_lin/obj/base/events.o ./build_lin/obj/base/packet.o ./build_lin/obj/base/pqueue.o ./build_lin/obj/base/protocol.o ./build_lin/obj/base/accting.o ./build_lin/obj/base/upload.o
ranlib ./build_lin/obj/lib/libbase.a
make dest=linux XPORT_MEDIA=-DTRANSPORT_MEDIA_SOCKET -f src/custom/custom.mk dmtpd_all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/centos/Downloads/OpenDMTP_client-c_1.2.0'

Making sample DMTP reference implementation ...

Make dmtp object dirs ...
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/custom
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/custom/linux
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/custom/modules
/bin/mkdir -p ./build_lin/obj/dmtp


Linking 'dmtpd' ...
cc -o ./build_lin/obj/dmtp/dmtpd -Wall -DTARGET_LINUX -DTRANSPORT_MEDIA_SOCKET -DPROTOCOL_THREAD -DGPS_THREAD -Isrc /usr/lib/libpthread.so /usr/lib/libm.so ./build_lin/obj/custom/startup.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/transport.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/log.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/gps.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/gpsmods.o ./build_lin/obj/custom/linux/os.o -L./build_lin/obj/lib -lmodule -lbase -ltools
cc: /usr/lib/libpthread.so: No such file or directory
cc: /usr/lib/libm.so: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [dmtpd_exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/centos/Downloads/OpenDMTP_client-c_1.2.0'
make: *** [dmtp_socket] Error 2
```

Comment: Maybe your libm and libpthread lives elsewhere? For example, on my machine they are in /usr/lib64, since I've got a 64-bit machine.

Comment: Which would mean if this is building 32 bit you need to install the 32 bit libraries.

Comment: How I verify the directory or How can I change it?

Comment: My machine is under VirtualBox(32 bits) hosted in a Win7 Core i5 machine

Comment: To find: `find /usr/lib* -name libm.so`

Answer (score 0):

From the archive you link to I see in /OpenDMTP_client-c_1.2.3/make/common.mk at line 54:

```
 SOLIBS    = $(LINUX_LIBS)/libpthread.so $(LINUX_LIBS)/libm.so
```

This is an odd way of giving these libraries on linux and is not likely to work. They are special system libraries and do not live in such predictable locations. The normal way to specify them is with -lm and -pthread (without the l).

As a quick hack editing /OpenDMTP_client-c_1.2.3/make/common.mk hack and replacing line 54 with:

```
 SOLIBS    =
```

and modifying line 82 to be:

```
 ALIBS       = -L$(LIB_DIR) -lmodule -lbase -ltools -lm -pthread
```

Should solve the problem. Though I'm not sure of the effect on the other platforms.